# What is the equivalent C code for this assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

```
add    0x4025c0(,%rcx,4),%edx
```

So I'm trying to convert this piece of assembly code into the actual C expression, can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Updated:
The code is actually part of this assembly program:

```
   0x00000000004010fe <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x00000000004010ff <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x0000000000401102 <+4>:     callq  0x401341 <string_length>
   0x0000000000401107 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x000000000040110a <+12>:    je     0x401111 <phase_5+19>
   0x000000000040110c <+14>:    callq  0x4015bf <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401111 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401116 <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x000000000040111b <+29>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
   0x000000000040111f <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x0000000000401122 <+36>:    add    0x4025c0(,%rcx,4),%edx
   0x0000000000401129 <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000040112d <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
   0x0000000000401131 <+51>:    jne    0x40111b <phase_5+29>
   0x0000000000401133 <+53>:    cmp    $0x33,%edx
   0x0000000000401136 <+56>:    je     0x40113d <phase_5+63>
   0x0000000000401138 <+58>:    callq  0x4015bf <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040113d <+63>:    pop    %rbx
   0x000000000040113e <+64>:    xchg   %ax,%ax
   0x0000000000401140 <+66>:    retq
```

Comment: it's much easier to read in Intel syntax `add edx, [rcx*4+0x4025c0]`

Answer (score 3):

```
add    0x4025c0(,%rcx,4),%edx
```

means

```
%edx += *(0x4025c0 + %rcx*4);
```

%rcx is a register in x64 asm. Here 0x4025c0 is the base address. *4 illustrates that the size of array element is 4 bytes (32 bits). So it can be translated into

```
%edx += *(uint32_t)0x4025c0[%rcx];
```

The whole code snippet does the following thing:

```
void check(char *str)
{
    const uint32_t *subTable = 0x4025c0;

    if (strlen(str) == 6)
    {
        uint32_t j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            j += subTable[str[i]];
        if (j == 0x33)
            return;
    }
    call explode_bomb;
}
```

A substitution table is stored in address 0x4025c0. Only when the input is of length 6 and the sum of its substitution numbers is 0x33, it will pass the check.

Answer (score 2):

Simply expressing it in C is something like `edx += ((uint32_t *)0x4025c0)[rcx];` But it's rather impossible to know what it's being used for without more context.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have updated my question and I couldn't figure out what the code is doing. I think that it's accepting a string witch consists 6 chars and after some operation in the middle it checks if the final answer is 0x33. Could you please explain to me that what the line is doing this program? That's will be really appreciated since I've been on this problem for a very long time :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the brackets are to be of the form

```
displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)
```

which is expanded as,

```
[base register + displacement + offset register * scalar multiplier].
```

So,

```
0x4025c0(,%rcx,4)
```

is,

```
(0x4025C0 + value at RCX * 4)
```

and

```
ADD    (0x4025C0 + value at RCX x 4), %edx
```

should mean,

```
edx += (0x4025C0 + ((*rcx)*4));
```

It means that after execution of this instruction, for example, if value at `RCX` is 100 (0x64), then `EDX` will hold the value `0x4025C0 + 0x190`.

Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have updated my question so you can see what is going on here... I guess my question is that what does this line do in the program specifically, could you please help me on this?

Comment: The last line expressed in C-like syntax is wrong. It's the value stored in edx, not the value pointed to by edx, that's modified, and the addend is not the value you wrote on the RHS but rather the 32-bit word pointed to by the RHS.